# Trouble getting nav bar to highlight selected tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble figuring this out.  I need the selected tab to be underlined when you're on that page.  So when you're on the settings page I need the settings tab to be underlined, and when your on the account page I need the account tab to be underlined.  Not sure what I’m doing wrong.  I'm not that good at JavaScript or CSS.

This is what I need:
[pic of tabs with underline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUjjF.png)

This is what I’m getting:
[pic of tabs without underline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmC6F.png)

codepen: https://codepen.io/Mike5678/pen/oNdgvbJ

```
<div id="nav">
<div class="icons-box">
    <a href="login.html" class="icons-links"><span onclick="addSelected()" class="material-icons">account_circle</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="icons-box">
    <a href="settings.html" class="icons-links"><span onclick="addSelected()" class="material-icons">settings</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

```
#nav {
    background-color: #171a1c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end
}

.icons-box {
    border-left: 1px solid #808080;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.icons-box.selected {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #b57917;
}
```

```
function addSelected() {
    $(".icons-links").click(function(event){
        $(".icons-box").removeClass("selected");
        $(".icons-box").addClass("selected");
    })
}
```

Comment: There is a problem in your `addSelected()` function.

Comment: this can't work, you're trying to set a `selected` class style to a link on click event. this will be applied briefly, while loading the new page, then will be lost. you have to track the current page in another way to set that class on DOM load.

Comment: The problem here is I don't even really know what the DOM is.  I've been reading about it, and I've got a lot better.  But it's not my language.  If everything was done with python....it would be easier

Comment: it's about the logic: you have two links pointing to `login.html` and `settings.html`. I guess when a user clicks on one of them, you want it to be redirected to the new page. And when that new page loads, that's when you want to set the `selected` style on the icon representing the current page. is this what you need to accomplish?

Comment: @Mike you could learn more about the DOM from https://www.codeguage.com/courses/js/html-dom-introduction. I find it to be an amazing resource with many exercises to practice.

Comment: @GrafiCode yes that is what I want to accomplish.

Comment: @coderboy I will look into it thanks.  I do need to learn web development

Comment: @Mike You're welcome. I find [CodeGuage's course](https://www.codeguage.com/courses/js/) on JavaScript to be very very good for beginners. There are many exercises to practice concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment, your current code tries to set `selected` class style to a link on click event. This will be applied briefly, while loading the new page, then it will be lost.

In order to set that class when the new page is loaded, you could check whether the current page URL (`location.href`) contains the current page name, like this:

```
$(function() {
  let currentURL = location.href;
  
  if (currentURL.includes('login.html')) {
    $('a[href="login.html"]').addClass('selected');
  } else if (currentURL.includes('settings.html')) {
    $('a[href="settings.html"]').addClass('selected');
  }
});
```

With CSS:

```
.icons-links.selected {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #b57917;
}
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  I was wondering why it was only being applied briefly.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, every answer I got was useful and helped me.  Grafi, your answer was very useful thanks I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code reads

```
$(".icons-box").removeClass("icons-box");
$(".icons-box").addClass("selected");
```

In the first line, you query the element with the class `icons-box`, and remove its class.

In the second line, you try to query the element with the class `icons-box`, but you won't get anything back, because you just removed the class from that element in the previous line --- e.g. there will now be no elements on the page that match the `.icons-box` selector!

---

I'd suggest either swapping the order of these two statements, or better yet keeping one class on the elements that you can use to reference them, and one which controls the styling

Comment: Actually that was a copy paste mistake.  It still doesn't work when it's fixed.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me @Mike https://jsfiddle.net/d3txuzvq/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct definition of `addSelected()`, given that you remove the `onclick` HTML attribute from your HTML elements `.icons-links` (it's good design practice to keep JavaScript away from HTML files):

```
$(".icons-links").click(addSelected);
function addSelected(event) {
    $(".icons-box").removeClass("selected");
    $(this.parentNode).addClass("selected");
    return false;
}
```

Here's what's happening here:

The `selected` class is removed from all `.icons-box` elements and then that same class is added to the parent of the `.icons-links` element clicked. The `return false` statement is given to prevent the default action that happens as the link is clicked. You can even use `event.preventDefault()`.